# haskell recursive function

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

Please help me writing a function which takes two arguments: a list of ints and an index (int) and returns a list of integers with negative values on specified index position in the table.

The function would have this signature`MyReverse :: [Int]->Int->[Int]`.

For example: `myReverse [1,2,3,4,5] 3 = [1,2,-3,4,5]`.

If the index is bigger than the length of the list or smaller than 0, return the same list.

Comment: This smells like homework. If so, tag it as such.

Comment: `itemInverse` (or `inverseItem`) would be a better name, as "reverse" implies an entirely different operation on lists.

Comment: or `negateItem`. Inverse can mean 1/x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myReverse :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
myReverse [] n = []
myReverse (x:xs) n
 | n < 0     = x:xs
 | n == 0    = (-x):xs
 | otherwise = x:(myReverse xs (n-1))
```

That's indexing the array from `0`; your example indexes from `1`, but is undefined for the case `n == 0`. The fix to take it to index from `1` should be fairly obvious :)

Also, your capitalisation is inconsistent; `MyReverse` is different to `myReverse`, and only the latter is valid as a function.

Results, in GHCi:

```
*Main> myReverse [10,20,30,40,50] 0
[-10,20,30,40,50]
*Main> myReverse [10,20,30,40,50] 2
[10,20,-30,40,50]
*Main> myReverse [10,20,30,40,50] 3
[10,20,30,-40,50]
*Main> myReverse [10,20,30,40,50] 5
[10,20,30,40,50]
*Main> myReverse [10,20,30,40,50] (-1)
[10,20,30,40,50]
```

More generic version that does the same thing, using a pointless definition for `myReverse`:

```
myGeneric :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
myGeneric f [] n = []
myGeneric f (x:xs) n
 | n < 0     = x:xs
 | n == 0    = (f x):xs
 | otherwise = x:(myGeneric f xs (n-1))

myReverse :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
myReverse = myGeneric negate
```

Comment: thanks, my solution didnt work because of lack ob brackets in (-x):xs

thanks for help

Comment: @snorlaks: If you have a partial solution, people will always appreciate you posting it with the question, and saying what you've tried, where you think the problem is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

myReverse :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
myReverse [] _ = []
myReverse list n
|length list < n = list
myReverse (x:xs) n
|n == 0 = -x : myReverse xs (n-1)
|otherwise = x : myReverse xs (n-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
myReverse :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
myReverse [] _ = []
myReverse list n
   |length list < n = list
myReverse (x:xs) n
   |n == 0 = -x : myReverse xs (n-1)
   |otherwise = x : myReverse xs (n-1)
```